# How to Load PE Files for Process Hollowing?

Tags: c++, load, system, portable-executable

The target is `notepad.exe`

The code to insert is a PE file called Hello.

PE FILE:
[image]

Error:

```
error occurred --> if (IDH->e_magic== IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE
error content is "Exception through: read access violation. IDH was 0xC4."
```

The following is the whole code.

```cpp
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <TlHelp32.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <tchar.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string>
    #include <tchar.h>
    #include <locale.h>


    #define FILE_PATH ("C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe")
    #define PE_FILE_PATH ("C:/Users/code1/Desktop/Hello.exe")


    typedef LONG(WINAPI* NtUnmapViewOfSection)(HANDLE ProcessHandle, PVOID BaseAddress);

    void ProcHollowing(LPSTR szFilePath, PVOID ); //pFile);
    PVOID pFile();

    int main(){
        ProcHollowing((LPSTR)(FILE_PATH), pFile());

        return 0;
    }

    PVOID pFile() { //PE파일의 DATA 추출 부분 (.text 추출)
        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)PE_FILE_PATH, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Fail: Hello.exe 파일이 없습니다.");
    }

    return hFile;
    }

    void ProcHollowing(LPSTR szFilePath /*TargetProc*/, PVOID pFile/*PE Data*/) {
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER IDH;/*PE 구조의 첫 시작부분 DOS 헤더*/
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS INH;/*PE헤더*/
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER ISH; //섹션 헤더
    PROCESS_INFORMATION PI; //프로세스 정보
    STARTUPINFOA SI; //생성시 프로세스에 대한 윈도우 스테이션, 데스크탑, 표준 핸들 및 주 창의 모양을 지정하는 구조체.
    PCONTEXT CTX;
    PDWORD dwImageBase; //생성된 프로세스의 Image Base 주소
    NtUnmapViewOfSection NewNtUnmapViewOfSection;
    LPVOID pImageBase;
    int Count;

    IDH = PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(pFile);

    if (IDH->e_magic== IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE/*PE 파일이 맞는지 시그니처를 통해 확인한다.*/) { //IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE는 4D5A 즉 MZ
        _tprintf(TEXT("SUCCESS: This is PE File\n"));
        INH = PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS(DWORD(pFile) + IDH->e_lfanew); // Dos header의 끝부분 + 시작 부분으로 PE Header를 구하는 것.

        if (INH->Signature == IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE/*시그니처 확인하여 PE포멧 파일인지 구분*/) {
            _tprintf(TEXT("SUCCESS: PE FILE Check\n"));

            RtlZeroMemory(&SI, sizeof(SI)); // SI의 크기만큼 0으로 채워준다는 의미. 즉, 초기화
            RtlZeroMemory(&PI, sizeof(PI));
            bool bResult = CreateProcessA(szFilePath/*실행할 모듈의 이름 notepad.exe*/, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &SI, &PI); // 정상 프로세스를 생성. SUSPENDED 상태.

            if (bResult) {//프로세스가 잘 생성되면
                _tprintf(TEXT("SUCCESS: CreateProcessA\n"));

                CTX = PCONTEXT(VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeof(CTX), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE)); //CTX 가상 메모리 할당.
                CTX->ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL; //Context 구조에서 초기화해야하는 부분을 나타내는 값.

                if (GetThreadContext(PI.hThread, LPCONTEXT(CTX))/*프로세스 정보 획득*/) {
                    ReadProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPCVOID(CTX->Ebx + 8), LPVOID(&dwImageBase), 4, NULL); /*Image Base 주소 구하기*/
                    //ebx에는 PEB 주소가 들어가 있고 PEB+8에는 Image Base 주소가 들어가있다. 
                    //PEB(Process Environment Block)에는 해당 프로세스에 대한 정보가 들어가있음.
                    _tprintf(TEXT("SUCCESS: Get Image Base Address\n"));

                    if (DWORD(dwImageBase) == INH->OptionalHeader.ImageBase) { //Image Base와 PE Header의 OPTIONAL HEADER의 Image Base가 같으면
                        NewNtUnmapViewOfSection = NtUnmapViewOfSection(GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"),
                            "NtUnmapViewOfSection")); //메모리 할당해지 핸들이랑 주소
                        _tprintf(TEXT("SUCCESS: Unmap\n"));
                        NewNtUnmapViewOfSection(PI.hProcess, PVOID(dwImageBase)); //정상 프로세스의 메모리 할당 해지
                    }
                    else {
                        _tprintf(TEXT("FAIL: Unmap\n"));
                    }

                    pImageBase = VirtualAllocEx(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(INH->OptionalHeader.ImageBase), //재할당
                        INH->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, 0x3000, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

                    /*악성코드 데이터 삽입 부분 같은데 여기부분 이해 잘 안됨.*/
                    if (pImageBase) { //재할당 완료 되면
                        _tprintf(TEXT("SUCCESS: Reassignment\n"));
                        WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, pImageBase, pFile,/*pFile, 즉 데이터를 넣어주는 부분같음.*/
                            INH->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, NULL);//악성코드 삽입(?) 헤더를 바꿔주는 거같음.

                        for (Count = 0; Count < INH->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; Count++) {
                            ISH = PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER(DWORD(pFile) + IDH->e_lfanew + 248 + (Count * 40));

                            WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess,
                                LPVOID(DWORD(pImageBase) + ISH->VirtualAddress),
                                LPVOID(DWORD(pFile) + ISH->PointerToRawData),
                                ISH->SizeOfRawData, NULL);
                        }
                        WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(CTX->Ebx + 8),// 메모리 쓰기. Image Base
                            LPVOID(&INH->OptionalHeader.ImageBase),
                            4, NULL);

                        CTX->Eax = DWORD(pImageBase) + INH->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint; //AddressOfEntryPoint는 PE파일이 메모리에 
                        //로드된 후 맨 처음 실행되어야 하는 코드의 주소가 포함되어 있음.
                        //Eax는 Original Entry Point(OEP)가 들어가 있음. 즉, 실행 프로그램의 실제 시작 위치
                        SetThreadContext(PI.hThread, LPCONTEXT(CTX)); //프로세스 정보 변경
                        ResumeThread(PI.hThread); //프로세스 재실행
                    }
                    else {
                        _tprintf(TEXT("FAIL: Reassignment\n"));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    _tprintf(TEXT("FAIL: Get Image Base Address\n"));
                }
            }
            else {
                _tprintf(TEXT("FAIL: CreateProcessA\n"));
            }

        }
        else {
            _tprintf(TEXT("FAIL: PE FILE Check\n"));
        }
        VirtualFree(pFile, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    }
    else {  //PE파일이 아니면 
        _tprintf(TEXT("FAIL: This is not PE File\n"));
    }
}
```

Comment: This site says process hollowing is a malware technique: https://www.andreafortuna.org/2017/10/09/understanding-process-hollowing/
Thus, I won't be helping.

Comment: @CodeLurker they might just be studying the process and might not have any malicious intent. Generally, it is advisable to assume good faith and act accordingly.. but at the end of the day, it is your call.

Answer (score 1):

There are too many things to fix for excution

I will not upload the modified code because there are some parts that were not implemented..

First,

```
PVOID pFile(){ // hFile is a HANDLE but ret type is PVOID... hmmm
...
    //HANDLE hFile = CreateFile((LPCWSTR)PE_FILE_PATH, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0); // <-- GENREIC_WRITE? and CREATE_ALWAYS?
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile($file_name, GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
...
```

You should read MSDN Docs CreateFile
You create a file handle, but there is no reading method (like API ReadFile)
^ This is the cause of the error.

```
...
if (DWORD(dwImageBase) == INH->OptionalHeader.ImageBase) {
NewNtUnmapViewOfSection = NtUnmapViewOfSection(GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"),
    "NtUnmapViewOfSection"));
NewNtUnmapViewOfSection(PI.hProcess, PVOID(dwImageBase)); 
...
...
WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(CTX->Ebx + 8),
                        LPVOID(&INH->OptionalHeader.ImageBase),
                        4, NULL);
...
```

STUDY ASRL!

```
...
CTX->Eax = DWORD(pImageBase) + INH->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint; 
                    SetThreadContext(PI.hThread, LPCONTEXT(CTX));
                    ResumeThread(PI.hThread);
...
```

You ResumeThread before write the  Dos Header, Dos Stub, PE Header in child process Memory

you have to fix entire codeㅠㅠ :(